# Django and pytest, multiple databases, preserve deletion

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql, pytest

In my project I am using multiple databases, 3 to be precise. 
One default and two reference databases (another host), which are powered and updated by our data team. I am using 4 tables from 2 external databases, which were inspected with `./manage.py inspectdb`. They are set to `managed=False`
Everything works fine, my application works as expected and planned.

Now the fun begins, I need to write tests. I do not want to delete my databases. 
I need to read from them, I do not want to create fixtures. 
Every time when I try to use pytest or custom django tests, it is trying to delete my databases, recreate, run migrations and stuff.

How can I preserve that ? Either in pytest or django tests ?  I've tried to --re-usedb, and couple of another params.

This is my database settings (parts which can be uploaded)

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
        'NAME': 'default_db',
        'USER': 'default_usr',
        'PASSWORD': 'default_pass',
        'HOST': 'postgres.somehost.com',
        'SUPPORTS_TRANSACTIONS': True,
    },
    'geolocations': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'options': '-c search_path=some_schema'
        },
        'NAME': 'geo_name',
        'USER': 'geo_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'geo_password',
        'HOST': 'some-host.domain.com',
        'SUPPORTS_TRANSACTIONS': True,
    },
    'eoc': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'options': '-c search_path=another_schema'
        },
        'NAME': 'eco_name',
        'USER': 'eoc_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'eoc_',
        'HOST': 'some-another-host.domain.com',
        'SUPPORTS_TRANSACTIONS': True,
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So inside of pytest.ini you should be able to add a '--no-migrations' flag in order to ensure that migrations are not being made.  Using a pytest marker [pytest documentation](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/mark.html) should enable you to have access to your database.

The mark you need is:

```
pytestmark = pytest.mark.django_db
```